# sound on mouseOver and mouse Click HTML <audio>

Tags: html, audio, mouseover

I can't get any sound from this code and I don't know why.

```
<body>
    
    <audio id="linkSound" src="sound/link_effect2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio id="enterSite" src="sound/intro.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" preload="auto"></audio>
    
    <div>
        <a href="introduktion1.html" onmouseover="document.getElementById('linkSound').play()" onclick="document.getElementById('enterSite').play()">Welcome to my site</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: your code should work. make sure that the sound file is being loaded properly. also when clicking the link, it will redirect immediately

Comment: by loading you mean that the path should be correct right? I've dobble checked and it's correct - but doesn't work. What do you mean by "when clicking the link, it will redirect immediately"?

Comment: i tested your code on my local machine and it works fine.
when you click the link, it will redirect to "introduktion1.html" immediately thus the song will not play or will just play for a few seconds

Comment: which browser were you testing it?

Comment: you are right. It seems that my poblem is the sound only plays if I've adjusted the sound leven on my computer just before mouseing over the link... strange. Do you know how I can make the sound continue even after the introduktion1-page is loaded?